$L^1$ function with zero average on balls of fixed radius
Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be a function such that
\begin{align*}
\int_{B_1(x_0)} f(x)\,dx = 0
\end{align*}
for every $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^d$ (where $B_1$ denotes the unit ball). I want to prove that $f = 0$ a.e. This should be easy in theory (it was left as an exercise to some undergraduate friends of mine), but I wasn't able to find a simple solution. Some considerations:

(a) The $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ assumption has to play a role, there are counterexamples when $f$ is simply $L^1_{\text{loc}}$.
(b) The case $d=1$ is indeed straightforward, one can simply consider the difference $\int_{B_1(x)} f - \int_{B_1(y)} f$ and obtain that $f$ must be periodic.
(c) One could apply the Fourier transform to $f*\chi_{B_1}$ and obtain that $\mathcal{F}(f) \mathcal{F}(\chi_{B_1})=0$. This should imply $\mathcal{F}(f)=0$ (and thus $f=0$), but I would prefer not to deal with Bessel functions and their zeroes (moreover, in theory my friends don't know yet what a Fourier transform actually is).

Any idea? For reference, assume that the solution should only make use of basic properties of the convolution and $L^p$ spaces.

Pretty sure that Lebesgue had something to say about this. At least almost everywhere.

There are measurable functions. See here. The example described are not $L^1$, though.

Ignore my comment, I missed the unit part.

@SassatelliGiulio that's exactly the point (see my Edit). The $L^1$ assumption has to play a role, otherwise any periodic function of period 1 with 0 mean is a counterexample in dimension 1!

Pick a Lebesgue point around $x$. Then pick two balls which overlap like a venn diagram at $x$; as you move the balls away from each other so that $x$ remains in the intersection, the overlap is an evenly shrinking neighborhood whose integral goes to $0$; by differentiation it follows that $f(x)=0$.

We can write $R_d$ as the countable union of compact sets $K_n$. Now for each $K_n$ we can cover with a countable union of unit balls, thus we can find a write $R_d$ as a countable union of unit balls. Denote an enumeration of such covering by $B_{n}$. Then $\int_{R_d} |f| d \mu = \lim_{N=1}^{\infty}\int_{\cup_{n \leq N}B_{n}} |f| d \mu = 0$. Note this equality holds by dominated convergence theorem and the assumption that $f$ is $L^{1}$ (thus $|f| \in L^{1}$). Now that we have $\int_{R_d} |f| d\mu = 0$ we can proceed as normal by considering the level sets of $f$ and arguing towards a contradction.

your unit balls are not disjoint., so how do you justify that $\lim_{N=1}^{\infty}\int_{\cup_{n \leq N}B_{n}} f d \mu = 0$ ? Also $f$ might change sign so $\int_{R_d} f d\mu = 0 $ is not enough to conclude

You're right, instead, we can for each ball use the monotonicity of the integral to see that $\int |f| = 0$ for any unit ball. Then we can consider a sequence of functions approaching $|f|$ from below, and using the fact that $|f| \in L^{1}$, apply dominated convergence to extend to the whole domain.  Now we can show $|f| =0 $ almost everywhere the usual way and get that $f=0$ almost everywhere.

Specifically, since $|f|$ is in $L_1$ and $|f| \chi_{\bigcup_{n \leq N} B_n} \leq |f|$, we have $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f| d\mu = \lim_{N \to \infty} \int |f| \chi_{\bigcup_{n \leq N} B_n} d\mu$ = $\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{\bigcup_{n \leq N} B_n} |f| d\mu$. But for each $N$, we have $\int_{\bigcup_{n \leq N} B_n} |f| d\mu \leq \sum_{n \leq N} \int_{B_n} |f| d\mu = 0$. Thus, $0 = \lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{\bigcup_{n \leq N} B_n} |f| d\mu = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f| d\mu$.
